# Crear ruta personalizada en flask

Tags: python, flask

estoy intentando crear una ruta personalizada en flask (apliacion/perfil/<carnet_del_usuario>) y estoy intentando lo siguiente

```
@app.route('/perfil<int:carnet>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def perfil():
    carnet = session["carnet"]
    print(type(carnet))

    return render_template('perfil.html', carnet=carnet)
```

y dentro de mi index tengo un link a esa ruta de la siguiente manera:

```
{% block links %}
    <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center"><a class="nav-item nav-links" href="/perfil/{{carnet}}">Perfil</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center"><a class="nav-item nav-links" href="/logout">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
{% endblock %}
```

carnet es un entero. A la hora de darle click en el navegador solo sale /perfil y vacio. Lo que quiero lograr es que cada usuario tenga su ruta personalizada en base a su numero de carnet aplicacion.com/perfil/1234 pero al parecer esa no es la manera. Como puedo solucionarlo para que funcione a como espero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Te saltaste una '/'**

**2. En la funccion tienes que poner como parametro el nombre de la ruta**

```
@app.route('/perfil/<int:carnet>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def perfil(carnet):
    # carnet = session["carnet"] Esto en este caso no tiene sentido porque el valor ya te lo da la funccion
    print(type(carnet))

    return render_template('perfil.html', carnet=carnet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que falta un `/` en la definición de la ruta. Por otro lado no sé por qué admites el verbo POST en esa ruta, que se entiende que es de solo lectura (es decir, que no le vas a enviar datos, sino solo a pedirlos). Si ese es el caso, basta usar el verbo GET y ya que ese es el que se usa por defecto no sería necesario el parámetro `methods`.

En definitiva, quedaría así:

```py
@app.route('/perfil/<int:carnet>')
@login_required
def perfil():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

El `.route()` le va a pasar a la función el argumento que le indiques con el `<type:name>`, no te dado un error porque tienes la función de login en medio, el argumento es requerido así que no va a existir la ruta `/perfil/` y si la quieres tienes que crear otro método

```
@app.route('/perfil/<int:carnet>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def perfil(carnet):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        datos = {
            'carnet': carnet
        }
        return render_template('perfil.html', **datos)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        return 'OK', 200
```